# Angularjs $scope value updated in second controller not visible in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have one html file and a controller assigned via $routeProvider

```
.when('/page/:pageId', {
            templateUrl: 'xxxx.html',
            controller: 'PageCtrl'
        })
```

and in the controller.js file i am accessing the value of pageId using `$routeParams` in 'PageCtrl' function.

```
  pageId = $routeParams.pageId;
```

and in view the html is

```
<div ng-controller="headerController">
  {{page.pageId}}
</div>
```

so in html i want to display the pageId, if pageId is passed in the url.

so here my question is once the pageId is passed its going correctly to the pageCtrl in Js and `pageId` scope value assigned, and am also able to assign the same scope value to the second controller 'headerController' by `$controller('headerController', {$scope: $scope});`

able to see that scope value is getting updated from one controller to another controller but my problem is that scope value which is updated, unable to view in html (`{{page.pageId}}`)

Comment: can you provide an example of what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your controller is getting instantiated twice: once from your `$controller` call and another time from the `ng-controller` directive in your view, each time with a difference scope, where the latter "wins" as far as what shows up in your view goes.

Consider this [**small demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HEinQYK05hug9kbk0ZZM?p=preview):

JS

```
.controller('FirstController', function($scope, $controller){
   console.log('FirstController', $scope.$id); // logs 003
   $scope.pageId = '12345';
   $controller('SecondController', {$scope: $scope});
})
.controller('SecondController', function($scope){
    console.log('SecondController', $scope.$id); // logs 003 & 004
    $scope.scopeId = $scope.$id; // second scope "wins", appears in view
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController"></div>
<!-- {{scopeId}} outputs a value while {{pageId}} does not -->
<div ng-controller="SecondController">Scope: {{scopeId}} Page: {{pageId}}</div>
```

A better solution is to [use a service to share data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers) between controllers.